# Possible to use createNewDocumentWithRedirect to redirect to a web based Infopath form?

Tags: web-part, infopath, forms-services, content-editor-web-part

We create a link to a InfoPath client-based form (meaning that the form is open at the client machine which have infopath installed.) by using the following source code inside a **Content Editor web part**

`<IMG alt="" src="/_layouts/images/rect.gif">&nbsp;<A onclick="createNewDocumentWithRedirect('http:\u002f\u002fwww.yoursite.com\u002fsce\u002fSubSiteName\u002fListName\u002fForms\u002ftemplate.xsn', 'http:\u002f\u002fwww.yoursite.com\u002fsce\u002fSubSiteName\u002fListName', 'SharePoint.OpenXmlDocuments.2', true, 'http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/ListName/Forms/template.xsn', 0);return false;" href="#">New ListName Document</A>`

whereby

- `www.yoursite.com` to the name of your site
- `SubSiteName` to the name of the sub site inside your site.
- `ListName` to the name of the list that you are performing on.

So, my question is:

Is it possible to use the same function - `createNewDocumentWithRedirect` to redirect into a **web-based** infopath form (meaning that when I click the link, it open a web-based infopath form without the need to have Infopath installed on the client machine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I believe you need to change only the Form URL you are using with the attribute `OpenIn` having value `"Browser"` or the `DefaultItemOpen` attribute with value 1. Please visit [this msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417.aspx) for more parameters that can help you with the InfoPath URL.

So your URL will ultimately look like this -

`<IMG alt="" src="/_layouts/images/rect.gif">&nbsp;<A onclick="createNewDocumentWithRedirect('http:\u002f\u002fwww.yoursite.com\u002fsce\u002fSubSiteName\u002fListName\u002fForms\u002ftemplate.xsn', 'http:\u002f\u002fwww.yoursite.com\u002fsce\u002fSubSiteName\u002fListName', 'SharePoint.OpenXmlDocuments.2', true, 'http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/ListName/Forms/template.xsn&OpenIn=Browser', 0);return false;" href="#">New ListName Document</A>`

Note the change - `&OpenIn=Browser` added in the URL above.

You can also check out [this blogpost](http://lambertqin.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/how-to-open-infopath-form-in-new-window-by-clicking-a-new-button-in-sharepoint-libraries/) for detailed info on how `createNewDocumentWithRedirect` works in core.js file.

Last but not the least, also make sure that [your form library is browser enabled](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepointinfopath/thread/68122772-A20C-40F0-8193-B2C48331E68B) to help the InfoPath form open in browser.

Comment: I tried the URL above but it still open the InfoPath client even though I have set the form library to browser enabled and have ensure that the InfoPath form is web-based. Any clues why it is so?

Comment: can u try just this part in your browser -`http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/ListName/Forms/template.xsn&OpenIn=Browser` .If that works, then its some problem with the complete URL. If your form is set to open in browser, go to the library and click on new item, which should open in browser. If it does, then we need to check that URL and compare whats the difference. You can also try DefaultItemOpen=1 at the end of the url instead of Openin=browser. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Deepu, it works if just using this URL - `http://www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://‌​www.yoursite.com/SubSiteName/ListName/Forms/template.xsn&OpenIn=Browser`. Look like I have to debug the complete URL.